# Logic App - Refer and map fields on different JSON data sources

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have two JSON data sources:

**Source Data 1:**

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "resource_list": "7961b907db9253045fbdf1fabf9619d4,55617907db9253045fbdf1fabf9619d2",
            "project": "11216",
            "project_manager": {
                "value": "55617907db9253045fbdf1fabf9619d2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Source Data 2:**

```
{
    "result": [
        {
        "sys_id": "7961b907db9253045fbdf1fabf9619d4",
            "email": "test.user1@mysite.com"
        },
        {
            "sys_id": "55617907db9253045fbdf1fabf9619d2",
            "email": "test.user2@mysite.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to reference ***"resource_list"*** and ***"project_manager"*** from **Source Data 1** to ***"sys_id"*** in **Source Data 2** and get ***"email"*** out from **Source Data 2** and then compose a final **Output** like below:

**Output:**

```
[
    {
    "__metadata":
        {
        "uri": "ProjectCode"
        },
    "externalProject": "11216",
    "projectCodeAssignment":
        [
            {
            "__metadata":
                {
                "uri": "projectCodeAssignment"
                },
            "externalProjectAssignee": "test.user1@mysite.com"
            },
            {
            "__metadata":
                {
                "uri": "projectCodeAssignment"
                },
            "externalProjectAssignee": "test.user2@mysite.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is this possible to get this done entirely in Logic App without using Function App or anything to perform it rather.

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved?  Could you please accept my  post if it is helpful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a js script for you. For a quick demo, I omitted some data related to `__metadata`, seems that is some hard code, not so important here. Try Logic below:

[image]

Code in JS code action:

```
var body = workflowContext.trigger.outputs.body
var data1 = body.data1;
var data2 = body.data2;

var result = [];

data1.result.forEach(item =>{
    var resultItem = {};
    resultItem.externalProject = item.project;
    resultItem.projectCodeAssignment =[];
    
    var resourceIds = item.resource_list.split(',');
    resourceIds.forEach(id =>{
        var user = data2.result.find( ({ sys_id }) => sys_id === id );
        resultItem.projectCodeAssignment.push({"externalProjectAssignee": user.email})
    });
    result.push(resultItem);
    
})

return result;
```

Request Body(your 2 data set are named as `data1` and `data2` here ):

```
{
    "data1": {
        "result": [{
                "resource_list": "7961b907db9253045fbdf1fabf9619d4,55617907db9253045fbdf1fabf9619d2",
                "project": "11216",
                "project_manager": {
                    "value": "55617907db9253045fbdf1fabf9619d2"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "data2": {
        "result": [{
                "sys_id": "7961b907db9253045fbdf1fabf9619d4",
                "email": "test.user1@mysite.com"
            }, {
                "sys_id": "55617907db9253045fbdf1fabf9619d2",
                "email": "test.user2@mysite.com"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stanley for a quick and easy solution; however, to run a JavaScript we require an Integration Account I guess? I don't have an Integration Account. Sorry bit new in this area, any alternate solution to run JavaScript or something else on LogicApp which works without needing an Integration Account?

Comment: @VictorMcIntyre,Welcome, yes, an Integration Account is needed if you excute JS here. You are free to create an Integration Account , just follow this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code#prerequisites